# Making sure a painted string doesn't leave the visible area?

Tags: java, swing, awt

The task that was give to me was to visually exemplify an algorithm using java: I have to simulate a heap structure.

**The expected layout.**

[image: The expected layout]

The problem I am facing is how to make sure that the painted strings in the code area are not leaving the visible area indifferently the screen resolution. I already make sure that the JFrame has the screen size - the taskbar size. The panel is maximized and the isResizable property is false.

So how can I make sure that the strings don't leave the visible area?

The code that I want to draw:
It do not matters if the code is more long (Y dimension) that the container wat it matters is X Dimension.

*I tried printing it line by line.*

```
public class heap<T>
{
    private ArrayList<T> h;
    private int size;
    private final Comparator<T> c;

    public heap(Comparator<T> comparator)
    {
        h = new ArrayList<T>();
        h.add(null);
        size = 0;
        this.c = comparator;
    }

    public T getMin()
    {
        return h.get(1);
    }

    public T popMin()
    {
        T tmp = getMin();
        h.set(1, h.get(size));
        size--;
        sift(1);
        return tmp;
    }

    public void insert(T key)
    {
        h.add(key);
        percolate(++size);
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }

    private int getLeftSon(int i)
    {
        return (i<<1<=size)? i<<1 : 0;
    }

    private int getRightSon(int i)
    {
        return ((i<<1)+1<=size)? (i<<1)+1 : 0;
    }

    private int getFather(int i)
    {
        return ((i>>1)!=0)? i>>1 : 0;
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j)
    {
        T tmp = h.get(i);
        h.set(i, h.get(j));
        h.set(j, tmp);
    }

    private void sift(int i) 
    {
        int son;
        do {
            son = 0;
            if (getLeftSon(i) != 0) 
            {
                son = getLeftSon(i);
                if (getRightSon(i) != 0 && c.compare(h.get(getRightSon(i)), h.get(getLeftSon(i))) > 0) 
                    son = getRightSon(i);
                if (c.compare(h.get(son), h.get(i)) <= 0) 
                    son = 0;
            }

            if (son!=0) {
                swap(i, son);
                i = son;
            }
        } while (son!=0);
    }

    private void percolate(int i) 
    {
        T key = h.get(i);

        while ((i > 1) && (c.compare(key, h.get(getFather(i))) > 0)) 
        {
            h.set(i, h.get(getFather(i)));
            i = getFather(i);
        }

        h.set(i, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: Please show us a [Runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you have tried so far...

Comment: *"Making sure a painted string doesn't leave the visible area?"*  I typically turn the `String` into a `Shape` or `Area` prior to painting.  Then it is easy to get the height and width of the bounding box of the shape and scale it to need.

Comment: Use a `JScrollPane` and allowing the child component to expand to meet the needs of it's content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code area is rather narrow, on the order of 25 characters rendered in a mono space 12 point font.

Here's one way to see if a String will fit in a given pixel width:

```
    public boolean doesStringFit(int width, String s, Font font) {
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
        int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
        int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
        return width >= (rWidth - rX);
    }
```